# Failed to load next.config.mjs

Tags: next.js

trying to start https://github.com/sadmann7/skateshop after git clone
and getting this

- error Failed to load next.config.mjs, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
  Error: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\Lmao\Desktop\newReact\skateshop\skates\skateshop\node_modules.pnpm@effect-ts+otel-exporter-trace-otlp-grpc@0.15.1_@effect-ts+core@0.60.5_@opent
  elemetry+api@1.4_aul557yiuu22b5xwpe7cspv3aa\node_modules@opentelemetry\exporter-trace-otlp-grpc\package.json' imported from C:\Users\Lmao\Desktop\newReact\skateshop\skates\skateshop
  \node_modules.pnpm@effect-ts+otel-exporter-trace-otlp-grpc@0.15.1_@effect-ts+core@0.60.5_@opentelemetry+api@1.4_aul557yiuu22b5xwpe7cspv3aa\node_modules@effect-ts\otel-exporter-tra
  ce-otlp-grpc_mjs\index.mjs
  Did you mean to import @opentelemetry+exporter-trace-otlp-grpc@0.39.1_@opentelemetry+api@1.4.1/node_modules/@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc/build/src/index.js?
  at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:188:26)
  at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:769:14)
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:831:20)
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1036:11)
  at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:12)
  at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:140:32)
  at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:33)
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  type: 'Error',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
  }
   ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

I found this discussion https://github.com/contentlayerdev/contentlayer/issues/506
After adding override my package.json looks

```
{
  "name": "skateshop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "contentlayer build && next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "next lint --fix",
    "postinstall": "drizzle-kit generate:mysql",
    "db:push": "drizzle-kit push:mysql",
    "db:introspect": "drizzle-kit introspect:mysql",
    "db:studio": "drizzle-kit studio",
    "shadcn:add": "pnpm dlx shadcn-ui@latest add",
    "email:dev": "email dev --dir src/components/emails -p 3001",
    "stripe:listen": "stripe listen --forward-to localhost:3000/api/webhooks/stripe --latest",
    "typecheck": "contentlayer build && tsc --noEmit",
    "format:write": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,mdx}\" --cache",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"**/*.{ts,tsx,mdx}\" --cache"
  },
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "@opentelemetry/api": "1.4.1",
      "@opentelemetry/core": "1.13.0",
      "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc": "0.39.1",
      "@opentelemetry/resources": "1.13.0",
      "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "1.13.0",
      "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node": "1.13.0",
      "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "1.13.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.21.13",
    "@clerk/themes": "^1.7.5",
    "@clerk/types": "^3.46.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
    "@planetscale/database": "^1.8.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-aspect-ratio": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-email/components": "^0.0.7",
    "@react-email/tailwind": "0.0.8",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.6.0",
    "@tanstack/match-sorter-utils": "^8.8.4",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.9.3",
    "@uploadthing/react": "^5.1.0",
    "@vercel/og": "^0.5.8",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.6.1",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "contentlayer": "^0.3.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.27.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "8.0.0-rc10",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.29",
    "lucide-react": "^0.258.0",
    "next": "^13.4.8",
    "next-contentlayer": "^0.3.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-cropper": "^2.3.3",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.8.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-email": "^1.9.4",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
    "react-wrap-balancer": "^1.0.0",
    "resend": "^0.16.0",
    "sonner": "^0.5.0",
    "stripe": "^12.11.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.6",
    "unstyled-table": "0.0.3-alpha-3",
    "uploadthing": "^5.1.0",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2",
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.0.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "@types/eslint": "^8.40.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.3",
    "@types/prettier": "^2.7.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.61.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.61.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.19.3",
    "eslint": "^8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.13.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.3.0",
    "rehype-pretty-code": "^0.10.0",
    "rehype-slug": "^5.1.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "unist-util-visit": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

but still getting error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.